# Magento2.4 products are not getting displayed in catalog list page

Tags: magento2, reindex, elasticsearch

Magento2.4 products are not getting displayed on the catalog list page. I am feeling it is due to some elastic search issue.

**I used following command to Delete index**

> curl -X DELETE 'http://localhost:9200/magento2*'

But still not able to load the products on category pages.

It is like a random behavior some times on reindex products appear for some category & not for other

On running below commands status is yellow

> curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/_cat/health?v&pretty'

Since magento version is 2.4 so can't switch to MySQL

Please advice.

Magento cron does not execute "Catalog Search" index properly - it runs, but products in category pages do not appear. I even created a custom cron for that, but it did not help. I would like to use the original Magento cron instead of my custom one - it is only a workaround for testing purposes.

When I run "php bin/magento index:reindex" in the terminal it also runs successfully, but without results in the frontend.

Comment: Have you reindex your data ? **php bin/magento indexer:reindex**

Comment: yes but not working